# Can't register JQuery plugin in Zend_Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I can't seem to get the ZendX_JQuery working. The helper path just won't load, and therefore the plugin is not register. I've tried it all, added it in a bootstrap file, added in config, etc.
Bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initJqueryLoad()
    {

      $view = new Zend_View();
$view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
//return $view;
    }
```

My Config:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

phpSettings.date.timezone = "GMT+2"
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "JP_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZendX_"


resources.view.helperPath.JP_View_Helper = "JP/View/Helper"
resources.view.helperPath.ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper = "ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Sozfo_"


resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/data/sessions"
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 18000
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 18000

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
```

The error message:

```
Message: Plugin by name 'JQuery' was not found in the registry; used paths: JP_View_Helper_: JP/View/Helper/ JP_Controller_Helper_: JP/Controller/Helper/ Sozfo_View_Helper_: Sozfo/View/Helper/ : C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\application/helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/
Stack trace:

#0 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(1174): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('JQuery')
#1 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(610): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'jQuery')
#2 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(336): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('jQuery')
#3 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\application\layouts\baklans.phtml(23): Zend_View_Abstract->__call('jQuery', Array)
#4 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\application\layouts\baklans.phtml(23): Zend_View->jQuery()
#5 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\View.php(108): include('C:\Zend\Apache2...')
#6 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(880): Zend_View->_run('C:\Zend\Apache2...')
#7 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\Layout.php(796): Zend_View_Abstract->render('baklans.phtml')
#8 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\Layout\Controller\Plugin\Layout.php(143): Zend_Layout->render()
#9 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php(331): Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout->postDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(965): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->postDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#12 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#13 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\public\index.php(51): Zend_Application->run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved this for me, is to put the helper path in `""` instead of `''`;

```
   protected function _initJqueryLoad()
{

    $view = new Zend_View();

  $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
  $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet('/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css')
    ->setLocalPath('/js/jquery/jquery.php')
    ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js');
    $view->jQuery()->enable();
ZendX_JQuery::enableView($view);
return $view;
}
```

Somewhat of a glitch. Should Post this as a bug.

Comment: In the previous code you created new `ViewRenderer`, with another instance of `View`. This has nothing to do with double or single quotes.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but even without the other ViewRenderer, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> used paths: JP_View_Helper_: JP/View/Helper/ JP_Controller_Helper_: JP/Controller/Helper/ Sozfo_View_Helper_: Sozfo/View/Helper/ : C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\LTSSP\application/helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/

Basing on this, you may see that the ZendX directory is not scanned.

1. Register the path with helper broker
2. Add the path to autoloader (e.g. copy the files from Zend framework source archive or add the path to `ZendX` to the `include_path`)

In the `application.ini`:

```
resources.view.helperPath.ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper = "ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper"
```

In the `index.php`:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/home/user/www/library/ZendFramework/1.11.2/library', // Zend dir is here
    '/home/user/www/library/ZendFramework/1.11.2/extras/library', // ZendX dir is here
    '/home/user/www/library/misc',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

In view:

```
$this->jQuery()->enable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your ZendX  in library forlder, I think you could register JQuery view helper as follows in your Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initJsqueryLoad() {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper',     'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
}
```

The stuff in your config would not be needed then. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: @Janis Peisenieks. Did you try without all the stuff about ZendX, JQuery in your application.ini.

Comment: Yup, But I just found the answer. Posted it just now.